# Text Column not sorting correctly alpabetically

Tags: column, sorting

I've created a list with two columns.
It contains Country Name (first column) and their 2 character abbreviation (second column).

Example:

---

Italy - IT

---

Sweden - SE

---

United Kingdom - UK

---

I've setup the list to sort on the column with the name "2 Characters".

Problem I experience, is that the list is not sorted correctly.
There is a mix in the sorting. Like SE comes before IT.

What can be the cause to this?

[image]

Here is the settings for sorting the list for the view AllItems.
[image]

Comment: Can you add screenshot ?

Comment: Which order did you choose? asc or desc?

Comment: Any help from my answer? @Andreas

Comment: Unfortunately I am not able to add a screenshot at this moment. Will get back when I am at that customer. I choose Asc order. Unfortunately your answer did not help.

Comment: I guess the "2 character" column is the calculated column, and I think SP meet little trouble with sorting on calculated column.

Comment: @JohnThomas Checked, but the "2 Characters" column is not being calculated.

Comment: My suggestion: we drop all of the sort on view AllItems -> Save -> Sort by using arrow next to column '2 Characters'. Then we check it works or not. If  yes, maybe our sort on view make thing to hard to understand.

Comment: @JohnThomas Performed as suggested. No change. Still not in the right order.

Answer (score 2):

Modify your view and choose

> Show items in ascending order
>
> (A, B, C, or 1, 2, 3)

[image]

Now SE should not come before IT, see my screenshot

[image]

Comment: I've set it up just like in your screenshot. Yet it does not sort correctly.

Comment: Does `SE` contain any extra spaces ?

Comment: No, there are no extra spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you created/changed the view with sorting, but selected another view?
If not, please, attach a screenshot of the view settings.

Comment: I've checked that as well, but nothing that indicates that it should be conflicting somewhere.